# Gem environment for running rb-libsvm

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, svm, libsvm

I was hoping someone could clarify this really simply question about using gem tools that I had.

I am trying to run some code that uses `rb-libsvm`, and I successfully installed this using `gem install`; when I use `gem list`, `rb-libsvm` is listed. However, in the code, the command `./svm-predict` throws the following errors:

```
sh: ./svm-train: No such file or directory
sh: ./svm-predict: No such file or directory
```

Is there something else I need to get the gem working on my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you are running it on shell, you can test it in `irb` by following sample code from provided in the documentation from https://github.com/febeling/rb-libsvm

```
require 'libsvm'

# This library is namespaced.
problem = Libsvm::Problem.new
parameter = Libsvm::SvmParameter.new

parameter.cache_size = 1 # in megabytes

parameter.eps = 0.001
parameter.c = 10

examples = [ [1,0,1], [-1,0,-1] ].map {|ary| Libsvm::Node.features(ary) }
labels = [1, -1]

problem.set_examples(labels, examples)

model = Libsvm::Model.train(problem, parameter)

pred = model.predict(Libsvm::Node.features(1, 1, 1))
puts "Example [1, 1, 1] - Predicted #{pred}"
```

Comment: In irb, there is there is the following issue:
irb(main):010:0> problem.set_examples(labels,examples)
=> 2
irb(main):011:0> model = Libsvm :: Model.train(problem,parameter)
NameError: uninitialized constant Model
 from (irb):11
 from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
All the preceding code works. Additionally, code mentioned above I ran the code using ruby filename.rb on shell

Comment: The line "Libsvm :: Model.train(problem,parameter)" from above comment contains spaces around the double-colon, which is probably not what you intended, i.e. access to the Model class inside the Libsvm module.

Answer (score 0):

The gem doesn't include the command line tools. Please see the [README](https://github.com/febeling/rb-libsvm/blob/master/README.md).

For that, consider installing the whole package. Despite the name libsvm, it's actually a package with command line tools and Python bindings, alongside the library proper.